# OR operator usage

Tags: c#

I wrote some code that is supposed to compare some text (hashes) from two different textboxes. If the text is the same it says verified, if not it says no match. I was trying to implement something that says you actually need to have a value in the box to run the verification, so that it doesn't give a hashes verified result with two empty text boxes.

I did it like this, but it always returns hashes verified anyway, even if there's nothing in the textboxes.

```
        private void VerifyHashes(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string hashes_left = outputTextBox.Text;
        string hashes_right = output2TextBox.Text;

        if ((output2TextBox?.Equals(string.Empty) ?? true) || (outputTextBox?.Equals(string.Empty) ?? true))

        {
            Verification.Text = "Hashes required";
        }
            
         else if (hashes_right == hashes_left)
        {
            Verification.Foreground = Brushes.LawnGreen;
            Verification.Text = String.Empty;
            Verification.Text = "HASHES VERIFIED";
        }
        else
        {
            Verification.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            Verification.Text = String.Empty;
            Verification.Text = "HASHES DO NOT MATCH";
        }
    }
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: I doubt you meant to compare `output2TextBox` with `string.Empty`. `output2TextBox` is (presumably?) a textbox, not a string.

Comment: `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(hashes_left) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(hashes_right))`... Also that's not a recommended way to compare hashes...

Comment: @zaggler: in C#, both `|` and `||` are _"logical OR operators"_. The latter is short-circuiting while the former is not, but they are both considered OR operators. _"OrElse"_ is a VB.NET thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why make it more complicated?

```
if( outputTextBox.Text.Length==0 || output2TextBox.Text.Length == 0 ) 
{
    // one of the boxes is empty
} else {
  if( output2TextBox.Text.Equals(outputTextBox.Text) )
  {
     // match
  } else {
    // not a match
  }
}
```

The text of a textbox *is never null* and the `.Length` property of the string is sufficient to check if its empty.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing your textbox controls, rather than their `Text` properties, to string values; that's always going to be false.

```
if ((output2TextBox?.Equals(string.Empty) ?? true) || (outputTextBox?.Equals(string.Empty) ?? true))
{
    Verification.Text = "Hashes required";
}
```

As a result, your flow proceeds to this comparison

```
else if (hashes_right == hashes_left)
```

... which succeeeds because an empty string *does* equal an empty string.

You probably meant to do this:

```
if ((hashes_left?.Equals(string.Empty) ?? true) || (hashes_right?.Equals(string.Empty) ?? true))
{
    Verification.Text = "Hashes required";
}
```